# Dash components not found when running flask/dash app locally

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I have 3 apps created with Dash that are working perfectly if I run them independently and open them on my browser. However, I've been trying to create a Flask app that asks for credentials (user/password) and redirects to the corresponding dash app depending on the user.
I need these dash apps to be contained in a sub-folder within the directory (instead of pasting the whole script in the Flask app)
My Flask app runs correctly and I'm able to load it on my browser, but when I try to log with any user I get a "Loading..." page and the following errors on my browser's console:

polyfill@7.v2_12_1m1692245986.12.1.min.js:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
react@16.v2_12_1m1692245986.14.0.min.js:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
prop-types@15.v2_12_1m1692245986.8.1.min.js:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
dash_renderer.v2_12_1m1692245986.min.js:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
dash_core_components.v2_11_1m1692245986.js:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
react-dom@16.v2_12_1m1692245986.14.0.min.js:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
dash_core_components-shared.v2_11_1m1692245986.js:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
dash_html_components.v2_0_14m1692245986.min.js:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
bundle.v5_2_7m1692245986.js:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
dash_app3:33 Uncaught ReferenceError: DashRenderer is not defined
at dash_app3:33:86

I understand that the Dash library should provide these files, but no matter what I do, it does not work.

This is my Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from dash_app1.dash_app1 import app as dash_app1
from dash_app2.dash_app2 import app as dash_app2
from dash_app3.dash_app3 import app as dash_app3

app = Flask(__name__)

# Credentials
valid_credentials = {
    "user1": "password1",
    "user2": "password2",
    "user3": "password3"
}

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    username = request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']

    if username in valid_credentials and valid_credentials[username] == password:
        if username == 'user1':
            return redirect(url_for('dash_app1_route'))
        elif username == 'user2':
            return redirect(url_for('dash_app2_route'))
        elif username == 'user3':
            return redirect(url_for('dash_app3_route'))
    else:
        return "Invalid credentials"

@app.route('/dash_app1')
def dash_app1_route():
    return dash_app1.index()

@app.route('/dash_app2')
def dash_app2_route():
    return dash_app2.index()

@app.route('/dash_app3')
def dash_app3_route(): 
    return dash_app3.index()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and this is a test dash app does run independently, but not when pulled from the flask app:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Input(id='input', type='text'),
    html.Div(id='output')
])

@app.callback(Output('output', 'children'), [Input('input', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    return f"You entered: {value}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I want to be able to go into the flask app, which contains a simple landing page rendered with an index.html file, and then continue to the corresponding dash app depending on the user.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are starting the Flask server, however it is never linked to the Dash app instances.

What you need to do is either assign the Flask server that you create to the server attribute of your Dash apps, or restructure the code, so that you may call the Dash constructor by passing the Flask server.

For example you may change it to something like:

```
from flask import Flask
from dash_app1.dash_app1 import app as app1

server = Flask(__name__)
app1.server = server

@server.route('/dash_app1')
def dash_app1_route():
    return app1.index()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.run(debug=True)
```

I found this article useful regarding linking Dash apps to existing Flask apps: https://blog.finxter.com/dash-flask/